# Setting up multiple parameter sets

Tags: powershell

I am working on a function that contains multiple parameter sets with some being mandatory.

i want the sets to be setup in a particular way but no combination I setup seems to be working correctly.

Function Requirements:

- Function can use either `$OrganizationName`, `$IsUserRepo` or neither
- Function must use either `$AllEvents` or, one or more from a list of CustomEvents. Default is `$AllEvents`

Examples of what I want to be able to call:

```
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -WebHookURL 'https://something.com' -AllEvents
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -OrganizationName 'OrgName' -WebHookURL 'https://something.com' -AllEvents
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -IsUserRepo -WebHookURL 'https://something.com' -AllEvents
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -WebHookURL 'https://something.com' -CommitComment -Create (ect...)
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -OrganizationName 'OrgName' -WebHookURL 'https://something.com'  -CommitComment -Create (ect...)
Test-Function -RepoName 'name' -IsUserRepo -WebHookURL 'https://something.com'  -CommitComment -Create -Delete (ect...)
```

Parameters I've been testing with:

```
Function Test-Function {
  [CmdletBinding(
    SupportsShouldProcess = $true,
    DefaultParameterSetName = 'OrganizationRepo'
  )]
  param(
    [Parameter(
      Position = 0,
      Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the name of the repository")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $RepoName,

    [Parameter(
      ParameterSetName = "OrganizationRepo",
      Position = 1,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the name of the organization account where the repository exists. Default: PowerShell. Ex: Windows-Server-Engineering")]
    [string]
    $OrganizationName = 'POWERSHELL',

    [Parameter(
      ParameterSetName = "IsUserRepo",
      Position = 1,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Repository exists under your personal GitHub account. Default: False")]
    [switch]
    $IsUserRepo,

    [Parameter(
      Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the URL to which the payloads will be delivered")]
    [string]
    $WebHookURL,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "OrganizationRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "IsUserRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'AllEvents',
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "All Events. Default: False")]
    [Switch]
    $AllEvents,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "OrganizationRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "IsUserRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'CustomEvents',
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Any time a Commit is commented on. Default: False")]
    [Switch]
    $CommitComment,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "OrganizationRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "IsUserRepo")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'CustomEvents',
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Any time a Branch or Tag is created. Default: False")]
    [Switch]
    $Create
  )
  # Continuing Custom Event Parameters
}
```

Comment: How many parameter sets do you need? Rather than examples of how you want to call the function, I recommend writing syntax descriptions on how you want the function to work before trying to design the code. Independent syntax descriptions naturally become parameter sets.

Comment: If I understand parameter sets correctly I should have 2 sets.  One set that allows for either `OrganizationName` or `IsUserRepo` and another set that allows for `AllEvents` or `CustomEvents`.  The default should be `OrganizationName` and `AllEvents`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand from your description, one way to do this is to use 6 parameter sets that would yield 6 possible invocations for the function (extra spaces inserted for readability):

```
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string>                                                     -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string>                            -CustomEvents <string[]> -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string> -OrganizationName <string>                          -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string> -OrganizationName <string> -CustomEvents <string[]> -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string> -IsUserRepo                                         -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
Test-Function [-RepoName] <string> -IsUserRepo                -CustomEvents <string[]> -WebHookURL <string> [-Create] [-CommitComment]
```

The code to produce this function prototype is as follows:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoAllEvents")]
param(
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoAllEvents",   Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoCustomEvents",Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoAllEvents",           Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents",        Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoAllEvents",          Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents",       Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String] $RepoName,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoCustomEvents",Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents",        Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents",       Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateSet("A","B","C")]
    [String[]] $CustomEvents,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoAllEvents",   Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents",Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String] $OrganizationName,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoAllEvents",   Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch] $IsUserRepo,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoAllEvents",   Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoCustomEvents",Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoAllEvents",           Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents",        Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoAllEvents",          Mandatory=$true)]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents",       Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String] $WebHookURL,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoCustomEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents")]
    [Switch] $Create,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="NoOrgOrUserRepoCustomEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="OrgRepoCustomEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoAllEvents")]
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="UserRepoCustomEvents")]
    [Switch] $CommitComment
)
```

This design does not use an `-AllEvents` parameter but rather `-CustomEvents` (which would imply "not all events").